# Case statement in sqlserver in where clause with else as always true

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have used the always true statement e.g. `1 = 1` in case statement of where clause in MYSQL with following syntax:

```
select * from tablename where 
(case when tablefield is not null then 
 then tablefield = 'value'
else 1 = 1 end)
```

I want to know how can i use else `1 = 1` (always true statement) in sqlserver/tsql case statement in where clause.

Comment: MySQL and/or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I just mixed up the query,I was intended to ask for a condition when parameter variable is null instead of tablefield 
In that case query may look like this :

select * from tablename where 
(case when parameterfield_or_variable is not null then 
 then tablefield = 'value'
else 1 = 1 end)

or when using parameterfield for value
(case when parameterfield_or_variable is not null then 
 then tablefield = parameter_field_or_variable
else 1 = 1 end)

The answer as per asked question @KHeaney is right.

However the query in tsql/sqlserver as described in mysql, will be like this :

select * from tablename
where tablefield = @parameterfield 
-- incase of comparing input parameter field with tablefield
or @parameter is null

so when @parameterfield will be null it will show all results otherwise it will restrict to only input value.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

you would not use case you would just write a multi conditional statement. In your case it would look like

```
Where (tablefield = 'value'
       OR tablefield is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the TSQL CASE function, you could do something like :

```
select * from tablename where 1 = 
(case when tablefield is not null then 
    (case when tablefield = 'value' then 1 else 0 end)
 else 1 end)
```

which could be simplified to :

```
select * from tablename where 1 = 
(case when tablefield is null then 1 when tablefield = 'value' then 1 
else 0 end)
```

You can leave out the "else 0" parts, as when no match is found, NULL is returned (which will not be equal to 1). i.e.:

```
select * from tablename where 1 = 
(case when tablefield is not null then 
    (case when tablefield = 'value' then 1 end)
 else 1 end) 

select * from tablename where 1 = 
(case when tablefield is null then 1 when tablefield = 'value' then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
select * from tablename
where tablefield = isnull(@parameter, tablefield)
```

Answer (score -1):

I know T-SQL and MySQL both provide `COALESCE`, which returns the first non-NULL value provided.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (COALESCE(`tablefield`, 'value') = 'value')
```

Comment: That isn't going to work as coded. You would need to replace 1 = 1 with 'value' so that if tablefield is null it replaces that with value.

Comment: @SeanLange I see. Thank you for the correction. I was parsing the `CASE` statement incorrectly.